# Can't rename application package without an error message on one project

Tags: android, eclipse

============update=============

I was able to edit all 18 classes in my application manually one at a time and get it published under a new name but this is not really an acceptable long term solution.  I would still like to know how to fix this problem.  As I said, I am able to change the package name of other applications, just not the one I care about.

Allen

---

I go to "application tools" then "rename application project" and I can rename a package except for the one I want to rename.  In that case, I get an exception:

The box that pops up is called **Refactoring**

The heading in the box is **A fatal error occurred while performing the refactoring**.

And the error message is:

**"An unexpected exception occurred while creating a change object.  See the error log for more details."**

Nothing shows up in the error log and I have no idea what to do.  I can easily rename other projects so I think I know the process. The application works fine and in fact is released on Google Play.  I want to create a second version for testing that times out in 10 days for people to try so it needs a different name.  Just changing the name in the strings file is not enough for Google Play to think it is a different project.

Almost any work around that can get this thing on Google Play as a different application would be just fine.

Any help would be appreciated as most of the posts deal with how to change the name when there is no error, which I can do.

Allen

---------------update--------------------
I found the error file an here it is:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$13.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1666)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1663)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.createChange(RefactoringWizard.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.computeUserInputSuccessorPage(RefactoringWizard.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.getStartingPage(RefactoringWizard.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showStartingPage(WizardDialog.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation$1.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:122)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.RenamePackageAction.initiateAndroidPackageRefactoring(RenamePackageAction.java:168)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.RenamePackageAction.promptNewName(RenamePackageAction.java:151)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.RenamePackageAction.run(RenamePackageAction.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.updateJavaFileImports(ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.java:149)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring$JavaFileVisitor.visit(ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource$2.visit(Resource.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource$1.visitElement(Resource.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.iterate(ElementTreeIterator.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:108)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.createChange(ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CreateChangeOperation.run(CreateChangeOperation.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Root exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.updateJavaFileImports(ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.java:149)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring$JavaFileVisitor.visit(ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource$2.visit(Resource.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource$1.visitElement(Resource.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.iterate(ElementTreeIterator.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:108)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.createChange(ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CreateChangeOperation.run(CreateChangeOperation.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Comment: please share the existing package name and the name you are trying to rename...

Comment: The existing package name is com.paloaltophoto.startline and I have tried a variety of names as I don't really care what it is called but mostly com.paloaltophoto.startline2limited

Answer (score 6):

The problem with mine is because I have a code file that is totally commented off, when the re factor tool scans through the files under my package it couldn't read it. Check through your codes make sure the .java files are all valid java files.

Comment: in my case, the class was blank

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled Eclipse.  Nothing else worked.

Comment: I try to reinstall and the problem remains